# Change in month in Android Calendar View calls setOnDateChangeListener

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I want to call an asynctask on change of a date. So I am using the following code which is working fine. But some unexpected things are happening here.

```
CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) root.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mont + "/"+dayOfMonth + "/" + year,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             EventsTask gt = new EventsTask(getActivity(), eventsList);
             gt.execute();

        }
    });
```

But this is also being called on change of month in calendar view which loads the same date.
What needs to be done here so that I can stop this from happening.

Comment: why -ve points man....I just can't figure what's going on....Did you even read the question....u might be some genius if you can solve every problem...what a way to reply back..kudos..

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, [Djomla1989](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184004/djomla1989) suggested a solution to this problem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586671/4179651). `onSelectedDayChange` will be called when scrolling to a different month, even though the `CalendarView`'s selected date doesn't change without clicking on a date. One must store the original selected date and determine if a new date was actually clicked on.