# Android CalendarView setOnDateChangeListener for selection only - not scrolling

Tags: android, calendarview

What am I missing in that I want to use a CalendarView to select a date.  Yet when I code up the following, the onCateChangeListener is called when I scroll.  I only want it to fire when a date is clicked.

```
  calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.v("#####", "Date Change: " + month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641250/android-calendarview-ondatechangelistener

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this as well as a hack, but didn't know if the platform had updated CalendarView to include an onClickForSelectedDate.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Zaki's suggestion on [Android: CalendarView OnDateChangeLIstener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641250/android-calendarview-ondatechangelistener) shows a solution - was just wondering if the Android Team had implemented an onClickHandler that would do that same thing.  Thanks Zaki for pointing this out.